# Pycurl is not successfully verifying a wildcard certificate

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, pycurl, wildcard-subdomain

I'm encountering an error in a Python application at a point where it's using pycurl to connect via HTTPS to a server.  (Note, in this case, the "server" is another Python utility which implements a simple HTTPS server with the `ssl` library providing the encryption.)  The "server" is providing a wildcard certificate which -- to my eye -- looks correct and looks like it should successfully verify.  But pycurl is rejecting it as a mismatch.

The code segment performing the pycurl connection is:

```
def request_pycurl(cls, url, data, timeout):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, [b'Content-Type: application/json'])
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2)
    c.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, timeout)
    if data is not None:
        c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url.encode('utf-8'))
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
    c.perform()
    return buf.getvalue()
```

The server certificate, generated in OpenSSL, has the common name `*.*.*.mycompany.com` with DNS SANs covering the spread of `mycompany.com` , `*.mycompany.com` , etc. all the way up to the three extra levels in the common name.  ("mycompany" here is an intentional redaction.)  The actual connection request's URL involves five elements.

When I run the app, the error that bubbles back up to the error logging function is:

```
error(60, "SSL: certificate subject name (*.*.*.mycompany.com) does not match target host name 'foo1.foo2.foo3.mycompany.com'")
```

I've done a search for any known issues relating to Pycurl and its handling of wildcard certificates, but nothing obvious came up.  In the course of searching I've also come across a bit of a puzzle, in any articles where I've found the above error message text, they always cite a different error number -- 51 instead of 60.

At any rate... can anyone tell me whether there's a code change needed to make pycurl accept the wildcard certificate?  Or whether there's a problem with pycurl that prevents it from handling wildcards properly?

Comment: Certificate wildcard names only work at ONE 'level' i.e. only the leftmost/first DNS label, never more. Re 51 vs 60, 51 was formerly used but not anymore, see https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLEPEERFAILEDVERIFICATION

Comment: Compare/neardupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037334/java-ssl-error-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025968/is-the-certificate-valid-for-the-url-dev-user-svc-databaker-io https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797306/issue-ssl-for-dyanmic-domain-like-wild-card https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627261/java-certificate-mismatch

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 -- thanks, these references help.  So in my example, what *should* work would be:  *.foo2.foo3.mycompany.com ... right?

Comment: Never mind, I just confirmed it myself -- it's working now.  Thanks!  If you re-enter the comments as an Answer, I can go & ahead and mark it accepted.